# Display current date with editable-date directive when form is editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, x-editable

I'm using the editable-date directive to allow users to change date information on a form, I want them to be able to see the current date when the form is in editable but currently it displays the current date format instead. How can I add this functionality?

```
 <td data-editable-date="user.dob">
      {{user.dob | date:'MMMM-dd-yyyy' }}
 </td>
```

[image]

Comment: According to the documentation you can just add a `e-datepicker-popup="MMMM-dd-yyyy"` attribute.  Is that all you needed? https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#bsdate

Comment: I'm using the angular bootstrap directive http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker, which does not use the e-datepicker-popup.

Comment: That has a `uib-datepicker-popup` attribute - but I'm not sure how you are using the x-editable library, if you create a small sample fiddle or plunkr we could figure out what options you may have.